# Why I keep get error like unexpected token when follow React.js tutorial

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

**[UPDATE]**: It turns out that I did not follow exactly as official sites says, which means **I need add "[  ]" in the command**.

---

All:

I am pretty new to react.js, when I follow [official site tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html), the steps I used is:

A. Build a file main.js

B. npm install -g browserify

C. npm install --save react react-dom babelify babel-preset-react

D. browserify -t babelify --presets react main.js -o bundle.js

**Then I get error like**:

```
SyntaxError: c:/Temp/web/lnreact/main.js: Unexpected token (6:2)
  4 |
  5 | ReactDOM.render(
> 6 |   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    |   ^
  7 |   document.getElementById('example')
  8 | );
    at Parser.pp.raise (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modul
es\babylon\index.js:1413:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_
modules\babylon\index.js:2895:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\no
de_modules\babylon\index.js:746:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-c
ore\node_modules\babylon\index.js:501:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\
node_modules\babylon\index.js:481:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\nod
e_modules\babylon\index.js:412:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel
-core\node_modules\babylon\index.js:394:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core
\node_modules\babylon\index.js:357:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-cor
e\node_modules\babylon\index.js:1224:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (c:\Temp\web\lnreact\node_modules\babelify\node_module
s\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\index.js:577:20)
```

**I am wondering where did I do wrong?**

Thanks

Comment: Did you import React into your main.js?

Comment: @JoshBeam I copy the same code in main.js from official site under "Using React from npm "

Comment: I think it's a JSX error

Comment: Yes it's a JSX error no doubt, but Babel/React should be taking care of that. Kuan can you post your package.json please?

Comment: @AndrewAxton Thanks, could you give me more detail about where is wrong and how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not appear to be running the command given in the tutorial. The correct command to run `browserify` should be this:

```
$ browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I think it for granted too much!

Comment: You're welcome! In the command you ran, `--presets` was being processed by `browserify` rather than the `babelify` transform, so nothing happens. In this command, we pass the presets to the transform, which works.

Comment: Thanks for this clearly helpful explaination, now I get it.